# How to install PhantomJS on J2EE Project?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, maven-3, phantomjs, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to install PhantomJS.
But i don't understand how to do it with maven
I'd like for instance print in a JSF page on Tomcat7

```
console.log('Hello, world!');
phantom.exit();
```

[phantomjs-maven-plugin](http://kylelieber.com/phantomjs-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html)
[arquillian-phantom-binary](https://github.com/qa/arquillian-phantom-binary)

If there is an another way without maven , it will be cool to share it too !

Answer (score 0):

I am using phantomjs for web crawling to get some links in jsf page.
My scripts are in a separate js files.
Whenever my jsf page is hit i execute required script and print the output to console.
Console output is read by the jsf page.

I am using Process to execute the script.

What you want to achieve with phantomjs?